# How to filter data without losing NA rows using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

[How to subset data in R without losing NA rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446165/how-to-subset-data-in-r-without-losing-na-rows)

The post above subsets using logical indexing. **Is there a way to do it in dplyr?**

Also, **when does dplyr automatically delete NAs?** In my experience, it removes NA when I filter out a specific string, eg:

```
b = a %>% filter(col != "str")
```

I would think this would not exclude `NA` values but it does. But when I use other format of filtering, it does not automatically exclude `NA`, eg:

```
b = a %>% filter(!grepl("str", col))
```

I would like to understand this feature of filter. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the package's author comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3196#issuecomment-342599352

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The documentation for `dplyr::filter` says... "Unlike base subsetting, rows where the condition evaluates to NA are dropped."

`NA != "str"` evaluates to `NA` so is dropped by `filter`.

`!grepl("str", NA)` returns `TRUE`, so is kept.

If you want `filter` to keep `NA`, you could do `filter(is.na(col)|col!="str")`

Comment: This solution won't do since if col != "str" returns FALSE but is.na(col) returns TRUE, it will be kept. So the filter fails.

I'm actually using both filter examples in one filter. So it goes b = a %>% filter(col != "str1", !grepl("str2", col)). This is what I do but it also filters out NA...that's the problem

Answer (score 18):

If you want to keep NAs created by *the filter condition* you can simply turn the *condition* NAs into TRUEs using [`replace_na`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html) from **tidyr**.

```
a <- data.frame(col = c("hello", NA, "str"))
a %>% filter((col != "str") %>% replace_na(TRUE))
```

Comment: This is the only solution that actually worked for me! Very elegant too! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue. It is very easy to miss, and I must say I find this behavior somewhat unintuitive. Based on qwr's answer, this is becoming a staple in all my projects from now on:

```
filter_na <- function(tbl, expr){
   tbl %>% filter({{expr}} %>% replace_na(T))
}
```

Comment: The behavior matches SQL WHERE in that it drops UNKNOWN in SQL's 3VL.