# dplyr filter function is dropping rows corresponding to empty values

Tags: dplyr, filter

I am trying to filter out some data. The code is as such,

df %>% filter(sortingvar, != "AA")

So the problem is that it is dropping all AAs but it is also dropping entire rows when there is a missing value for "sortingvar". The reason it is important is because in other columns, it does have important values.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter data without losing NA rows using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378437/how-to-filter-data-without-losing-na-rows-using-dplyr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `(NA != "AA")` is `NA`, not `TRUE`, so you need to explicitly check for `NA`, and include those rows.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
data <- data.frame(row=seq(9), sortingvar=c("AA", NA, "BB"))
data %>% filter(sortingvar != "AA")
#>   row sortingvar
#> 1   3         BB
#> 2   6         BB
#> 3   9         BB
data %>% filter(sortingvar != "AA" | is.na(sortingvar))
#>   row sortingvar
#> 1   2       <NA>
#> 2   3         BB
#> 3   5       <NA>
#> 4   6         BB
#> 5   8       <NA>
#> 6   9         BB
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>