# remove rows from dataframe based on value, ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe that I would like to delete rows from, based on a value in a specific column.
As an example, the dataframe appears something like this:

```
    a  b  c  d 
1   1  2  3  0
2   4 NA  1 NA
3   6  4  0  1
4  NA  5  0  0
```

I would like to remove all rows with a value greater than 0 in column d. I have been trying to use the following code to do this:

```
df <- df[!df$d > 0, ]
```

but this is appearing to have the effect of deleting all the value is rows with an NA value in column d. I was assuming that a `na.rm = TRUE`argument was needed but I wasn't sure where to fit it in the function above.

Cheers,
Ant

Comment: Try with `df[!(df$d > 0 & !is.na(df$d)), ]` or use `filter` from `dplyr` i.e. `df %>% filter(!d > 0)`

Comment: @akrun I've tried both methods. In each, the code seems to remove both all the rows with a value >0 in column d and all the rows with an NA in column d. There a way to keep the values where col d = NA (rows 1,2 and 4 in the example above).

Comment: Okay, I think I thought your condition is different.  You need the reverse condition in `is.na`

Comment: @RonakShah the code looks to have removed all the '>0' rows successfully but also seems to have converted all other values in the dataframe where d = NA to NA

Comment: @Ant seems to work on the sample data shared without any information changed. You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to select the rows where `d` is not greater than 0 OR there is `NA` in `d`

```
df[with(df, !d > 0 | is.na(d)), ]

#   a  b c  d
#1  1  2 3  0
#2  4 NA 1 NA
#4 NA  5 0  0
```

Or we can also use `subset`

```
subset(df, !d > 0 | is.na(d))
```

or `dplyr` `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!d > 0 | is.na(d))
```

---

The `!d > 0` part can also be reversed to

```
subset(df, d < 1 | is.na(d))
```

to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

We can construct the logical vector with `complete.cases`

```
subset(df, !d > 0 | complete.cases(d))
#   a b c d
#1  1 2 3 0
#3  6 4 0 1
#4 NA 5 0 0
```

Or use `subset` with `replace`

```
subset(df,  !replace(d, is.na(d), 0) > 0)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   filter(!replace_na(d, 0) >0)
```

which is slightly different from the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378437/how-to-filter-data-without-losing-na-rows-using-dplyr) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446165/how-to-subset-data-in-r-without-losing-na-rows)

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 4L, 6L, NA), b = c(2L, NA, 4L, 5L), 
c = c(3L, 1L, 0L, 0L), d = c(0L, NA, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If u add a `|`all rows that has a `NA` will match. The condition  `!df$d > 0` will get executed for those in `d` that are not a `NA`. So I think you were looking for:

```
df[is.na(df$d) | !df$d > 0,  ]
```

Wheras, the below wont include the rows that has a `NA` in column `d` and that does not match the condition `!df$d > 0`

```
df[!is.na(df$d) & !df$d > 0,  ]
```